# Re-prompt user on a Mobile Device if no response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have a mobile application which has a google assistant SDK integrated within and I want to re-prompt the assistant to say something like "Hey, I am still here, can I help ?" on 'no-input' from the user. I would like to know what could be the best approach to do that ?

I already went through a couple of links on stack overflow and github where I read that it is "not possible" to "re-prompt" on a Mobile Device as Assistant closes the microphone if there is no response from the user. What would be the best way forward -

1. Can I increase the timeout of when the assistant closes the microphone ?

   - I did figure out a way to keep the microphone always "ON", but it creates a "SERVICE UNAVAILABLE" error after few seconds and then the user has to re-start the service again which is not a good UX. Is there a way to mitigate the error, my investigation reveals it could be because of audio buffer ?
2. I read that we can use "Media Response" so that a Media is played while the user doesn't respond but is this the best approach ?

   - I also have a follow up question here, if I go with "Media Response" approach, is there a way I can explicitly close the conversation after say 30 secs of no user response ?

Some of the links I went through -

[Follow up intent for NO INPUT not firing with dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369796/follow-up-intent-for-no-input-not-firing-with-dialogflow)

[Reprompt user if no response in google action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605242/reprompt-user-if-no-response-in-google-action)

Can you please suggest a good approach to tackle this problem ?
My apologies if the question sounds silly, I am new to DialogFlow.

EDIT: - I also came across "continued conversation", is it possible to enable "continued conversation" from the assistant SDK, I searched but didn't find any documentation on that ?

Comment: I also went through follow-up intents as well as contexts but they don't really help in this scenario, any direction is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Is "media response" only solution ?